# How to override DependencyInjection part of bundle?

Tags: symfony

I am trying to override parts of FOSElasticaExtension https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle to handle configuration and parameters a little differently via bundle inheritance (somewhat described here http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/bundles/override.html). Unfortunately the documentation for this is lacking and I get strange errors (like configuration not getting injected at all) when attempting the override.

`vendor/acme/Acme/ElasticaBundle/AcmeElasticaBundle.php`

```
<?php
namespace Acme\ElasticaBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

/**
 * Extends FOS Elastica bundle.
 */
class AcmeElasticaBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSElasticaBundle';
    }
}
```

`vendor/acme/Acme/ElasticaBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php`

```
<?php
namespace Acme\ElasticaBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\ArrayNodeDefinition;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

use FOS\ElasticaBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration as BaseConfiguration;

class Configuration extends BaseConfiguration
{
}
```

`vendor/acme/Acme/ElasticaBundle/DependencyInjection/AcmeElasticaExtension.php`

```
<?php
namespace Acme\ElasticaBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\XmlFileLoader;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\DefinitionDecorator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;

use FOS\ElasticaBundle\DependencyInjection\FOSElasticaExtension as Extension;

/**
 * Overrides some parts of FOS Elastica extension.
 */
class AcmeElasticaExtension extends Extension
{
}
```

`app/AppKernel.php`

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new FOS\ElasticaBundle\FOSElasticaBundle(),
            new Acme\ElasticaBundle\PhoenixElasticaBundle(),
        );
    }
}
```

Error:

```
ErrorException: Notice: Undefined index: indexes in /home/tatsh/test-site/vendor/friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle/FOS/ElasticaBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php line 367
```

That is this line: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php#L367

I have not changed my configuration so I am not sure what could be the cause. I would think that their code that validates configuration is running fine and retrieving the values but the `MergeExtensionConfigurationPass` seems to not going properly with this:

```
in /home/tatsh/test-site/vendor/friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle/FOS/ElasticaBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php line 367
at ErrorHandler->handle('8', 'Undefined index: indexes', '/home/tatsh/test-site/vendor/friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle/FOS/ElasticaBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php', '367', array('nestings' => array())) in /home/tatsh/test-site/vendor/friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle/FOS/ElasticaBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php line 367
at Configuration->getNestings() in /home/tatsh/test-site/vendor/friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle/FOS/ElasticaBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php line 283
at Configuration->getMappingsNode() in /home/tatsh/test-site/vendor/friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle/FOS/ElasticaBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php line 265
at Configuration->getTypesNode() in /home/tatsh/test-site/vendor/friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle/FOS/ElasticaBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php line 188
at Configuration->addIndexesSection(object(ArrayNodeDefinition)) in /home/tatsh/test-site/vendor/friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle/FOS/ElasticaBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php line 30
at Configuration->getConfigTreeBuilder() in /home/tatsh/test-site/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Definition/Processor.php line 52
at Processor->processConfiguration(object(Configuration), array(array())) in /home/tatsh/test-site/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DependencyInjection/Extension.php line 103
at Extension->processConfiguration(object(Configuration), array(array())) in /home/tatsh/test-site/vendor/friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle/FOS/ElasticaBundle/DependencyInjection/FOSElasticaExtension.php line 23
at FOSElasticaExtension->load(array(array()), object(ContainerBuilder)) in /home/tatsh/test-site/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php line 42
at MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process(object(ContainerBuilder)) in /home/tatsh/test-site/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DependencyInjection/MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php line 39
at MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process(object(ContainerBuilder)) in /home/tatsh/test-site/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/Compiler.php line 119
at Compiler->compile(object(ContainerBuilder)) in /home/tatsh/test-site/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php line 453
at ContainerBuilder->compile() in /home/tatsh/test-site/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 950
at Kernel->buildContainer() in /home/tatsh/test-site/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 859
at Kernel->initializeContainer() in /home/tatsh/test-site/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 571
at Kernel->boot() in /home/tatsh/test-site/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 614
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in /home/tatsh/test-site/web/app_dev.php line 28
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to fix: Implement the `load()` method even if stub. Do not call the parent `load()` method.

```
<?php
/**
 * Overrides some parts of FOS Elastica extension.
 */
class AcmeElasticaExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
    }
}
```